# Using "in" operator in Django template not working as expected

Tags: django, django-templates

Could really use help figuring out what I'm misunderstanding about the following: I'm using the built-in "in" operator to check if a user (standard user model) is in a queryset of Board members.

This is the Board member model:

```
class BoardMembers(models.Model):
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name="memberships", blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user_boards', blank=True)
    member_role = models.CharField(choices=MEMBER_ROLES, max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Here is the view I'm using:

```
class ViewBoard(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.DetailView):
        model = models.Board
        select_related = ("user",)
        template_name = 'board/view_board.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(ViewBoard, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['boardmembers_list'] = BoardMembers.objects.filter(board__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

           return context
```

And this is the html part I'm struggling with:

```
{% if user in boardmembers_list %}

                    <h1>HEY, {{ user.username }}, YOU'RE ALREADY A MEMBER!</h1>

                    {% else %}
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'board:join_board' slug=board.slug pk=board.pk %}">Join this Board</a>

                    {% endif %}
```

I tested to see if individually the objects could be retrieved in the template and both the user and the boardmembers_list show up correctly.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator) it looks like this should be a relatively straightforward thing to do. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong or what I'm misunderstanding about how these operators work?

Comment: Presumably, `user` is an instance of User, and `boardmembers_list` is a list of, well, BoardMembers. So user will *not* be in boardmembers_list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its better to decide if the user is in board or not in the View, instead of template.

```
class ViewBoard(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.DetailView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        board_mem_list = BoardMembers.objects.filter(board__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        context = super(ViewBoard, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['boardmembers_list'] = board_mem_list
        context['user_in_board'] = board_mem_list.filter(user=self.request.user).exists()  # this will check if user is already in boardmemberlist

       return context
```

In template:

```
{% if user_in_board %}

     <h1>HEY, {{ user.username }}, YOU'RE ALREADY A MEMBER!</h1>

{% else %}
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'board:join_board' slug=board.slug pk=board.pk %}">Join this Board</a>

{% endif %}
```

And you are trying to search `user`in `boardmemebers_list`, and it won't work because **user** is a **User** model instance and **boardmemebers_list** is a queryset of **BoardMember** model where user is just a field of that model.